# How many ways can you give out 4 oranges, 2 bananas and 2 lemons

Tags: combinatorics

**How many ways can you give out 4 oranges, 2 bananas and 2 lemons between**

**a) 8 persons so that every person get exactly 1 fruit**

Hmm I wonder if I can use "Stars and bars" for this problem? :)

Comment: There are many ways. One of them is to send them into as fruit shop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use permutation with repetition: $${8!\over 4!2!2!}= 420$$

Comment: Ok thanks! Can you give an explanation for why "permutation with repition" is useful here and not this $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ for example?

Comment: Because if you redistribute say 4 oranges between same set of four people you have no change. So you must divde 8! by 4!

Comment: Can you unaccept answer today and accept it tomorow?

Comment: sure if i remember :P

Comment: I'll pin you...

Comment: Hello Daniel   .....

Answer (score 0):

Choose which four people receive an orange and which two of the four remaining people receive a lemon.  The other two people must receive a banana. Hence, there are 
$$\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$$
ways to distribute the fruits so that each of the eight people receives exactly one fruit.

To compare this answer with that provided by Maria Mazur, observe that 
$$\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} = \binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{2} = \frac{8!}{4!4!} \cdot \frac{4!}{2!2!} = \frac{8!}{4!2!2!}$$
The numbers in the denominator represent the number of ways we could permute the four oranges among the people who receive oranges, the number of ways we could permute the lemons among the people who receive lemons, and the number of ways we could permute the bananas among the people who receive bananas without changing which person receives which type of fruit.

Comment: Thanks makes the solution more understandable