# Number of ways to give out $4$ oranges, $2$ bananas and $2$ lemons between $2$ people, four fruit each?

Tags: combinatorics

**How many ways can you give out 4 oranges, 2 bananas and 2 lemons between**

**2 persons so that each person gets exactly 4 fruits?**

My attempt for a solution doesn't make sense. I tried with:

$\frac{2!}{2!2!4!}$

Comment: Is not $\frac{2!}{2!2!4!}$ a nonsense?

Comment: yes like i said it don't make sense. i tried to use the same logic as i used here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3230800/how-many-ways-can-you-give-out-4-oranges-2-bananas-and-2-lemons/3230802?noredirect=1#comment6646429_3230802

Comment: Does the "same logic" mean making some random choice of words to indicate a "research effort"?

Comment: yes sometimes you need to do what you need to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's 3 ways to split up the bananas:

- 2 to person 1, 0 to person 2
- 1 to person 1, 1 to person 2
- 0 to person 1, 2 to person 2

Similarly there's 3 ways to split up the lemons.

So there's $3 \times 3 = 9$ ways to split up the bananas and lemons.

After divying up the bananas and lemons, each person will between 0 and 4 fruit, inclusive.

Then there's exactly one way to divide up the oranges: make sure each person has 4 fruit total.

So 9 total ways.

Comment: Thanks i like your logic here :)